# laravel how to convert persian date to datetime format

Tags: laravel, datepicker

I have a persian datepicker in my view

```
<div class="input-group-addon" data-mddatetimepicker="true" data-targetselector="#exampleInput1" data-trigger="click" data-enabletimepicker="true">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput1" name="start_at"/>
```

and i have a column in my table that in datetime format

when I send this to controller and `dd($request['start_at']);` it returns `"۱۳۹۷/۰۷/۲۳ ۰۰:۰۰:۰۰"`

How to convert this to datetime format to save in database?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! :) Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.persiancalendar.todatetime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intro**

Everything that is related to date or time in Laravel should be done with `Carbon`. 
`Carbon` is a PHP Library/Extension to handle the formatting of Date and Time. You can find there docs over [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). `Carbon`is already included in Laravel, so check the API out over [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Carbon.html).

**Getting things done**

What you need to do is, pass in your timezone here:

```
$date = Carbon::now($start_at)->locale('UTC+6');
```

Assuming that the persia timezone is `UTC+6`the above snippet converts your time to a carbon time. 
After this you can access your timestamp with

```
$date->timestamp;
```

Or your DateTimeString with

```
$date->toDateTimeString();
```

*Please note:*  I am not absolutely sure about the time settings in persia. From a quick research I would assume that is UTC+6. You can also put in a string in the `locale()` function like:

```
$date = Carbon::now()->locale('fr_FR');
```

if this is easier to you!

**Quickshot URLs:**

- [Laravel Carbon API](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Carbon.html)
- [Carbon API](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: i catch this error   Unknown or bad timezone (1397/07/17 00:00:00)

Comment: instead of `locale()`try the `setTimezone()` function

Comment: no it's not working, i got this error : Unknown or bad timezone (UTC+6)

Comment: have you set the quotation marks around the timezone?

Comment: what timezone in string notation is persia? So whats the equivalent of `fr_FR` for persia?

Comment: Carbon cant convert Jalali(Shamsi) to other date formats. you should use other packages as @Shaielndra-Gupta suggested.

Answer (score 1):

use this package of laravel to convert date Persian to DateTime

[laravel persian datetime package](https://github.com/morilog/jalali)

Comment: Why should he add a package if there is even a more powerful package installed ?

Comment: don't know the Carbon class provide this functionality so I suggested him thanks for expanding my knowledge

Comment: than maybe edit your post in the way that you are sure that your solution is working but maybe there is a better way to doing so?